# Upload file docx on Godaddy ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: apache2, php, upload

since 3 weeks I'm having a problem with my linux server on Godaddy.

Well when I'm trying to send a file in POST to my php script I'm having this error : ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I tried to call technical support and they told me that everything was good.

I have tried to upload a file from my iphone on safari and it's worked.

I dont know why i'm having this error... maybe someone can help me?

I'm running apache with PHP 5.4

[image]

i have tried firefox, chrome and edge but i still have the same problem

Comment: Is this a Problem with Chrome(ium) (it shows up if you google the Error message)? Or where does the Error message show up?

Comment: i have updated my post. i have tried firefox, chrome and edge. If it can help you i can give you a link to try the upload.

Comment: Hm i'm afraid we need more info. 1. What are you uploading? - The Serverpages? 2.What do /var/log/apache/access.log and error.log say? 3. How is your Apache configured? httpd.conf etc. 4. If you are uploading to a php script, what is the code? - BTW you can always try to completely remove apache & etc and reinstall.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76333/connection-reset-no-data-recieved-all-of-the-time-on-my-website

Answer (score 0):

For those how have this error : ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE – No Data Received on Godaddy while trying to upload a .docx file .

It wont work because godaddy has blocked this extention file from being uploaded.